# Can anyone explain with a snippet code for training a Bayesian Network model for regression purpose

Tags: regression, training-data, pymc3, bayesian-networks

I have searched various documentations and references but unable to code Bayesian network model that has to be used for regression by training the given data and also to predict test data.

I will be thankful if anyone can provide a snippet code for it along with little explanation.

Comment: What is the preferred programming language?

Comment: python (python libraries using pymc3 or bayespy) @Jame Phillips

Comment: I suggest adding tags such as pymc3 and bayespy to the question.

Comment: Yes I have edited the question, if you know the solution can you help me out @James Phillips

Comment: I personally do not use pymc3 or bayespy.

Comment: Can you explain without libraries but considering an example for training and testing purpose in python @ James Phillips

Comment: bayespy has examples here: http://www.bayespy.org/examples/examples.html